# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tool'

Tags: python-3.x

from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tool.utils import Util

I have downloaded Util, tools moule still it shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tool'

Comment: Did you install the package? For example using ``pip3 install tools``

Comment: Please format your question structure correctly, such as code. If you are unsure how to do this refer to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple python installations, make sure you are installing the package for the correct python version. To install a package for python3.x use `python3.x -m pip install {package}`